# Syntax error while using ftp in loop

Tags: linux

I am trying to download the files from remote server by using the following script.

```
while read SERVER
do
  ftp -inv $SERVER << EOF
  user $USER $PASSWORD
  lcd $FILE_PATH
  cd $REMOTE_FILE_PATH
  mget *${FILE_TYPE}*
  bye
  EOF
done < $FILE_PATH/host_server
```

However, while executing I get the following error:

> ./File_downloader.sh: line 41: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: your "EOF" cannot be indented - the shell expects it to be the first thing on the line, with no trailing blanks. Alternatively, you can use "<<-EOF" that will strip off any leading _tabs_ (not spaces) before checking the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when reading text file with Windows-like end of line. Make sure that the file you are reading is in UNIX format (for example using the '*dos2unix*' utility.)

```
dos2unix path/host_server
```